# Error for Collections.sort using Comparable, Java

Tags: java, sorting, comparable

First-timer here, having a problem with this here Java code:
    
    import java.util.*;

```java
public class Pootis
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{   
    Superhero batman = new Superhero("Bruce", 26, "Batman");
    Human rachel = new Human("Rachel", 24);
    Superhero ironman = new Superhero("Tony", 35, "Ironman");
    Human pepper = new Human("Pepper", 22);



    List<Human> people = new ArrayList<>();
    people.add(batman);
    people.add(rachel);
    people.add(ironman);
    people.add(pepper);

    Collections.sort(people);//<-----
    }
}
```

The purpose of this program is to sort the people in the people ArrayList by age. I am using the comparable interface to this. The problem appears to be when the Collections.sort(people) is called. What did I do wrong??
This is the second class:

```java
public class Human implements Comparable<Human> {
private int age;
private String name;

public Human(String givenName, int age) {
    this.name = givenName;
    this.age = age;
}
@Override
public int compareTo(Human other){
    if(getAge() > other.getAge()){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(getAge() < other.getAge()){
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}


}
```

This is the error:

Pootis.java:65: error: no suitable method found for sort(List)
        Collections.sort(people);
                   ^
    method Collections.sort(List,Comparator) is not applicable
      (cannot instantiate from arguments because actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Collections.sort(List) is not applicable
      (inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
        inferred: Object
        bound(s): Comparable)
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method sort(List,Comparator)
    T#2 extends Comparable declared in method sort(List)
1 error

This is the Superhero class:

```java
public class Superhero {
String alterEgo, name;
int age;

public Superhero(String givenName, int age, String alterEgo) {
    super();
    this.alterEgo = alterEgo;
    this.name = givenName;
    this.age = age;
}

public String getAlterEgo() {
    return alterEgo;
}
public String introduce() {
    return "Hey! I'm " + name + " and I'm " + age + " years old. I'm also known as" + alterEgo + "!";
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The signature of `Collections.sort()` is:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)
```

This means that you can only call `sort` on a List of `Comparable` objects. Using `List<Object>` is not valid as `Object` is not a `Comparable`. `sort()` is overloaded with

```
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list,
                        Comparator<? super T> c)
```

but this is not applicable to your method call as you've only provided one parameter.

Bear in mind that, as per the javadoc, in order to sort a list using `Collections.sort()` all the elements must be mutually comparable. In your case it means that you should have a way of comparing a `Human` to a `Superhero`. Also, if `Superhero extends Human`, your list should be declared as a `List<Human>` (or viceversa).

Comment: I've made the change to the list, and I am still receiving errors:`AndroidReadiness.java:59: error: no suitable method found for add(Superhero)
        people.add(batman);
              ^
    method List.add(int,Human) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method List.add(Human) is not applicable
      (actual argument Superhero cannot be converted to Human by method invocation conversion)
    method Collection.add(Human) is not applicable`

Answer (score 0):

If `Superhero` extends `Human`, your list should look like

```
List<Human> persons = new ArrayList<>();
```

Because your objects inside the list are of type `Object` if you do it in another way and thus they can not be compared since `compareTo` is overridden in `Human`

Comment: I've tried that, but it's given me argument amount errors, etc. "AndroidReadiness.java:58: error: incompatible types
        List<Human> people = new ArrayList<Object>();
                             ^
  required: List<Human>
  found:    ArrayList<Object>
" etc.

Comment: Ok, would you mind posting your Superhero class please?

Comment: Ahh my bad but it still gives the same type of error relating to argument amount. `AndroidReadiness.java:59: error: no suitable method found for add(Superhero)
        people.add(batman);
              ^
    method List.add(int,Human) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)`

Comment: Would you mind posting the `Superhero` class please?